# How to map Id to private backing field in NHibernate's mapping by code?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

When using NHibernate's mapping by code functionality, how can I map the Id of an entity to a private backing field?

```
public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    private Guid? _id;

    protected Entity() { }

    protected Entity(Guid? id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    #region IEntity Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the unique id for this entity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The id.</value>
    public Guid? Id
    {
        get { return _id;
    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public abstract class GuidKeyedClassMapping<T> : ClassMapping<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    protected GuidKeyedClassMapping()
    {
        // What to write here???
        Id(x=> x.Id);
    }
}
```

Have tried with pointing out the property or field with string but to no avail.

```
Id(x => "_id", m => m.Access(Accessor.Field));
```

...gives me:

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in NHibernate.dll but
>   was not handled in user code Additional information: Invalid
>   expression type: Expected ExpressionType.MemberAccess, Found Constant

Answer (score 1):

`Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Access(Accessor.Field));` should work because `_id` matches `LowerCaseUnderscoreStrategy`. Note x.Id must be specified like in your first code